# Weird Move Object behavior

Tags: objects, edit-mode

Something went wrong I can't move my objects like it supposed to be. Description at the gif:
[image]

Comment: And HOW is it supposed to be? Add some details.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to disable *Snap during transformation*: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>